# Returning a specific value from a column based on the value of another column in the same row in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to Python dataframes.

In the following case:

| id | name | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cara | A |
| 2 | Ben | B |
| 3 | Evie | A |
| 4 | Mel | C |

I want to return the name of the student who has the first occurrence of result A (Cara). I want to then go and do the same for the second occurrence of A (Evie) and repeat until 5 occurrences. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
students=df.loc[df[result]=="A"].head(5)
print(student["name"].to_list())
```